# Record created by class in django models not getting recorded in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I created a table class in models.py in my django app. When I did the migration (into mysql), everything worked ok. I checked the mysql database and there are tables from django. One of the table is derived from the class that I created in models.py in django. I checked the structure of this mysql table, and it matches the attributes in my class.
Now I activate the django shell:

```
$python manage.py shell
```

I imported the class and created an instance.

```
>>> from tsts.models import Qstns
>>> Qstns.objects.all()
```

[Qstns is my class which represents the mysql table)
I get an empty set above, as there are no records.

Next I created an instance of this class Qstns, hoping that one record would be appended to my linked mysql table.

```
>>> q=Qstns(question='What is the capital of Australia?', subject='GK', topic='Countires', a='Sydney',b='Canberra',c='Melbourne',d='Brisbane',e='Adelaide',ans='b')

>>> q.save
```

These execute without any message.
Next I checked the id

```
>>>q.id
```

I do not get anything. It is expected to give me: 1. It looks like database table has not received this record.

```
>>>q.ans
```

It correctly gives me: 'b'

I logged into mysql and checked the linked table. It has not received the record.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance for your reply.
sp

Comment: Use object.save() not object.save. Save is a class method not class property.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine except one thing:
Use this:

```py
q.save()
```

instead of:

```py
q.save
```

Hope this will solve your problem.